# JQuery Mobile page navigation issues on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, jquerymobile, navigation

**Short Version**
I am having an issue with page state when a user clicks the Salesforce1 back arrow [image: Salesforce1 back arrow] when returning from a VisualForce page.

**Long Version**
My Salesforce1 app includes two separate Visualforce pages:

- Landing Page - This page is made up of three JQuery Mobile pages and includes two links which use `sforce.one.navigateToURL` navigation to the Related Data Page
- Related Data Page - This page is made up of its own JQuery Mobile page which is loaded with a standard `apex:repeat` VisualForce element and is a listing of related records

After changing JQuery Mobile pages on the Landing Page and then navigating to the Related Data Page the user must click the 
[image: Salesforce1 back arrow] button to return to the Landing Page. When the Landing Page reloads it has lost all state and shows the initial page.

So, if I had to summarize down to an actual question:
How can a JQuery Mobile enabled VisualForce page maintain its data/state when a user navigates "back"?

Comment: If you've not seen it, you may want to view the [Building Enterprise Apps Rapidly with SF Mobile](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Webinar:_Building_Enterprise_Apps_Rapidly_with_Salesforce_Mobile_Packs_(2013-May)) webinar. You might find the answers you seek within. Ideally, one creates a Mobile app with only one page then uses/refreshes only what they need.